# Xamarin Forms - Error in iOS Attempting to JIT compile

Tags: xamarin.forms

I have a xamarin forms app.  When I compile and test on my Pixel3, everything seems to be working properly.  When I load it up in my iOS device running iOS13.something, I get the following error when I try to make my second call to a web service in my app.  The error is shown below.

Assertion at /Users/builder/jenkins/workspace/archive-mono/2019-08/ios/release/mono/mini/interp/interp.c:2160, condition `is_ok (error)' not met, function:do_jit_call, Attempting to JIT compile method '(wrapper other) void object:gsharedvt_out_sig (object&,single&,int&,intptr)' while running in aot-only mode. See https://learn.microsoft.com/xamarin/ios/internals/limitations for more information. assembly: type: member:(null)

The code is a bit of a mess, but has been working in the past.

```
        var uri = String.Format("{0}//{1}/{2}?PlayerToken={3}", protocol, servername, tournamentsInClubUrl, userToken);
        var httpC = new HttpClient();
        HttpRequestMessage requestMessage = new HttpRequestMessage(HttpMethod.Get, uri);
        requestMessage.Headers.Add("AppKey", AppKey);
        var body = await httpC.SendAsync(requestMessage); <-- Error happens here.
        var str = await body.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
        var res = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<PicVideoApp.Models.TournamentInfo>>(str);
        httpC.Dispose();
        httpC = null;
        return res;
```

I assume that I am doing something wrong, but danged if I can see it.  Any ideas are appreciated.

It runs properly in the iOS Simulator.

TIA.

Comment: The simulator does not use JIT, but a device does.  What does the stack trace show?

Comment: I don't get a stack trace, just the following error before the app quits.  Link - https://justpaste.it/6hdap

Answer (score 1):

From shared error info , you need to use C# delegate to [call native functions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/ios/internals/limitations#using-delegates-to-call-native-functions) .

To call a native function through a C# delegate, the delegate's declaration must be decorated with one of the following attributes:

- **UnmanagedFunctionPointerAttribute** (preferred, since it is cross-platform and compatible with .NET Standard 1.1+)
- **MonoNativeFunctionWrapperAttribute**

For example :

```
[MonoNativeFunctionWrapper]
delegate void SomeDelegate (int a, int b);
//
// the ptrToFunc points to an unmanaged C function with the signature (int a, int b)
void Callback (IntPtr ptrToFunc)
{
var del = (SomeDelegate) Marshal.GetDelegateForFunctionPointer (ptrToFunc, typeof (SomeDelegate));
// invoke it
del (1, 2);
```

Comment: I apologize as I have been sick.

I am not quite sure why calling the SendAsync method on the http client is causing the JIT error.  Do you know why this could be happening?

Comment: @WallaceB.McClure Hi bro , how are you ? Taking care of yourself recently . Unforunaterly I'm not sure how this will happen , just knowing that Apple has this limitation .https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/ios/internals/limitations#no-dynamic-code-generation

Comment: yeah, I'm aware of the limitation. :-)  I found something I am chasing out in the Xamarin Forums.  I'm trying to juggle about 5 different things so I jump from one project of mine to another.

Comment: @WallaceB.McClure Awesome ！Then that will know more things about programming techniques *-^

Answer (score 1):

A similar error was thrown at me in iOS when I used dynamic types in my code. I was able to solve it by enabling the 'Mono Interpreter' in iOS build settings. Hope that helps in your case.

[image]

Comment: In case if someone face the similar issue in MAUI, pl refer -
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/maui/macios/interpreter